# Sort pandas dataframe by a column

Tags: python-3.x

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import datetime

# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'A' :[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
        'B' :[2,3,1,5,7,7,1,6]} 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df
```

I want to sort 'B' by each group of 'A'

Expected Output:

```
    A   B
0   1   1
1   1   2
2   1   3
3   1   5
4   2   1
5   2   6
6   2   7
7   2   7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort a dataframe using the sort_values command. This command will sort your dataframe with priority on A and then B as requested.

```
df.sort_values(by=['A', 'B'])
```

[Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)